# Elastic Search Query to select distinct values

Tags: elasticsearch

HI I want to get data from elastic search. I have sql query like this.

select distinct(brandvalue) from brands where brandvalue='nike';

I need this is in elastic search, I tried online converter to convert but it not works for me. Please help

I have data like this in elastic search db
[ Nike M NikeCourt Dry Tennis Short,
Nike M NikeCourt Dry Tennis Short,
Nike,
Nike W NikeCourt Pure Tennis Skirt,
Nike W NikeCourt Pure Tennis Skirt,
Nike M NikeCourt Dry Tennis Shirt,
Nike]
AMONG these when i seached with value nike . I want the result like below

[Nike M NikeCourt Dry Tennis Short,
Nike,
Nike W NikeCourt Pure Tennis Skirt,
Nike M NikeCourt Dry Tennis Shirt]

Comment: You will always get `nike`! you wanna get `brandvalue` where `brandvalue` = `nike` !!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you’re already familiar with the concept of aggregration, here’s all the code you’ll need to find the unique values of a field in Elasticsearch.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XGET "127.0.0.1:9200/<index_name>/<index_type>/_search?size=0&pretty" -d '
{
    "aggs": {
        "brandvalues": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "brandvalue"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```